# "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe." bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe, echo

I can run on command line this loop:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %i in ('arp -a ^| Find/i "dynamic"') do echo %i
```

but if I run the same bat file I get:

```
^C^C^C^Cthe process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^
```

C:\1\test.bat:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('arp -a ^ |Find/i "dynamic"') do echo %%i
```

Returned by your arp -a command:

```
C:\Users\test>arp -a
Interface: xxx.xx.xxx.40 --- 0xbe
Internet Address      Physical Address
 xxx.xx.xxx.18           xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
 xxx.xx.xxx.26           xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
 xxx.xx.xxx.34           xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
 xxx.xx.xxx.114          xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
```

thanks for any help //Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've introduced an additional whitespace character before the pipe, **`|`**. The caret, **`^`**, therefore has the effect of escaping the whitespace and the pipe isn't escaped as it should be.

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=2" %%i In ('arp -a ^| Find /I "dynamic"') Do @(Echo %%i)>>"%~dp0output.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, Compo,  but it's the same result again :(

Comment: Because there's nothing wrong with the command I have given you, the error must be caused by what is being returned by your `arp -a` command. How about you enter `arp -a` at the command prompt, then copy and paste the resulting output into your original question as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48318204/edit). When you do that, select the newly pasted section and press the button which looks like this **`{}`**, to put it into a readable format.

Comment: I copied and paste the resulting output of arp -a to my main question!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the command, I have given you and nothing wrong with the output you have added to your question. Perhaps you should check that your script hasn't got any strange encoding or control characters inside it. Use the built-in `notepad.exe` and paste my command above directly into it, then add `Pause` to the line below it and optionally `@Echo Off` to the line above it and `save as > all files > Location\And\NameOfYourChoosing.cmd`. Now execute it, check the output, and let me know what the result is.

Comment: Hi combo,
Nothing happens, but when I try to close cmd window the result will be:

Comment: ^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^^C^C^C^C^C^^C^C^C^C^^C^^C^C^^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^The process
tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

Comment: Please explain the process you used to try to close the window; _and please try to use my correct name_.

Comment: @user8785018: **don't** name your batchfile `arp.bat`!

Comment: ... or have some other `arp.bat` around.

Comment: … or `arp.cmd`!

Comment: Compo! I want to apologize for typing your name wrong! Sorry :(

Comment: I wasn't being serious about the name thing… Did you determine if it was your script filename or whether there is a file in the current directory or a location defined in `%PATH%` which also has the name `arp` with an extension as defined in `%PATHEXT%`?. _(you can see both of those things by entering `Set Path` at the Command prompt)_.

Comment: My file called test.bat is located in directory c:\1\. Set Path command is: PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC Can you do this differently? What I want is that I only have MAC addresses med "arp -a" command from the netwerk printed to a text file. I intended to send %%i  to set "MAC = %% i" and @echo! MAC !. But the loop (For) does not! work. Thanks for all help!

Comment: What is returned if you enter `Where arp` into your Command prompt? and you still haven't explained what you meant by, and how you were trying to close the window

Comment: c:\1>Where arp
C:\Windows\System32\ARP.EXE

Comment: Did you actually enter the commands into `notepad.exe` as I asked, and not some other editor, or did you think the fact I said `notepad.exe` was less important than it was. I need to determine that the content matches the ASCII text I used in my answer!

Comment: close the window: X close button in the top-right corner of the window.

Comment: Just double click the batch file, it will close itself when you press the pause button; or add `Exit` as a new last line; or just enter `Exit` at the prompt after running your script in the usual way. Or open a new Command prompt window and just enter this `Call C:\1\test.bat`

Comment: Nothing happen! If I press enter or pause nothing happens. Why do I try to close cmd windows with X close button and come:
^C^The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

Comment: If I do not close cmd windows computer get very slow! I guess (?) it starts processes in the background with cmd that uses memory! In the end, I have to turn off the computer with the off button.

Comment: I have updated my answer, just add that single line, exactly like it is into notepad and save as `test.bat` overwriting the existing one. Now run it by doubleclicking it. The result you want will be written to a file named output.txt in the same directory!

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks! :) I am very grateful for your patience and help and respect your knowledge. My final print in output.txt should have compiler names as well as me. Names should be same with increased numbers, from 1 to as long as arp finds mac addresses.
Ex. two-column printing with <tab> between
MAC <tab>Computername1
MAC <tab>Computername2

Answer (score 0):

to add the computername (when I interpret your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318204/the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe-bat-file#comment83679300_48319703) correct):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('arp -a^|find "dynam"') do (
  for /f "tokens=5" %%c in ('ping -a -n 1 %%a^|find "["') do (
    >>"%~dp0output.txt" echo %%a    %%b %%c
  )
)
```

shows `IP-address`, `MAC-address`, `Computer-name`. Adapt the `echo` line to your needs.
You may have to adapt the tokens (`tokens=5`) (inner `for`) for your language.
You may want to add `delims=.` to the inner `for` to get the computer name only.

according to your comments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set number=0
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('arp -a^|find "dynam"') do (
  set /a number +=1
  for /f "tokens=5" %%c in ('ping -a -n 1 %%a^|find "["') do (
    >>"%~dp0output.txt" echo %%b Computer!number!
  )
)
```

Output:

```
00-24-fe-xx-xx-xx  Computer1
f4-f5-e8-xx-xx-xx  Computer2
48-d6-d5-xx-xx-xx  Computer3
d4-85-64-xx-xx-xx  Computer4
80-86-f2-xx-xx-xx  Computer5
24-77-03-xx-xx-xx  Computer6
fc-db-b3-xx-xx-xx  Computer7
80-1f-02-xx-xx-xx  Computer8
```

Comment: Thank you that was great. But I want the output text to print new names on computers that only increase numbers on them, from eg computername1, computername2, etc. up to how much MAC addressees are available. I tried to resolve this with new variable set / A NUMBER + = 1 and send to echo coputername%number%, but it only writes computername1 to everyone. Probably it does not go to FOR lopp. How can I solve this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: you are nearly there. Read about [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).

Comment: Note that `arp -a` lists also old entries (computers that may be no longer available). If you just want active nodes, use `arp -d` before (clear chache), followed by a `ping -n 1 xxx.xx.xxx.255` ('xxx.xx.xxx' = your subnet, 255 for "Broadcast")

Comment: I tried it 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
in still output text is the same computername1 for all computers.

Comment: did you think to change `coputername%number%` to `coputername!number!` too?

Comment: I have tested both of them coputername%number% and coputername!number! But it is the same result, printing comutername1.

Answer (score 0):

I've received this error repeatedly when accidentally piping a batch script to MSYS `grep` when I really meant to grep a file afterward:

```
> call foo.cmd | grep pattern path\to\file
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
...
```

I haven't been able to identify exactly what `foo.cmd` needs to do to result in this error (my `foo.cmd` is pretty long and complicated), but I figured I'd add this here anyway. Hopefully it helps someone (even myself in a few months). What I meant to say was:

```
> call foo.cmd && grep pattern path\to\file
```